# x == y ? "1" : "5" How to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, controller

can someone help me with this code. i really dont know how to do this, also, i came up with this code, but it does not return the expected result.

```
<label><%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserInfo.DeliveryCode, "1" , Model.ChargeREFCode == "5" ? new { id = "DC1" , disabled = "true" } : new { id = "DC1" , disabled = "false" })%>受信する</label>
```

in if else condition:

```
if (Model.ChargeRefCode == "5")
{
this label must be disabled;
}
else
{
enabled;
}
```

Comment: `it does not return the expected result` a key element in getting help is to explain (clearly) what that expected result is and/or how your code fails.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to better understand the site

Comment: Well x == y checks if x is y, ? is ternary operator which sort of acts like an if. So if x is y then return "1" else return "5"

Comment: Also please make your code readable, no one wants to have to scroll for miles

Comment: i'm Sorry, I'm not good at english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issue is that you're always passing the `disabled` attribute.  You shouldn't pass this attribute if you want the radio button to be enabled.

```
<label><%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserInfo.DeliveryCode, "1" , Model.ChargeREFCode == "5" ? (object)new { id = "DC1" , disabled = "disabled" } : new { id = "DC1" })%>受信する</label>
```

Regarding the title:

Well x == y checks if x is y, ? is ternary operator which sort of acts like an if. So if x is y then return "1" else return "5"